# Why is $E(X_1^2)=1$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, expected-value

I need to show that $E(\chi_n^2)=n$. Since $E[\chi_n^2]=\sum_{i=1}^{n} E\left[X_{i}^{2}\right]=nE\left[X_{i}^{2}\right]$ where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and thus all I need to know is $E\left[X_{i}^{2}\right]$. In the solution they casually plug in $E\left[X_{i}^{2}\right]=1$, how do we know that?

Comment: Is $\chi=X$?  If so, thenn just use the fac that the variance is $1$ and, in general, variance is $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.

Comment: @Lulu Amazing, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to proceed is to realize that

$$X\sim\chi_{(n)}^2=\text{Gamma}\left(\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

where $\frac{1}{2}$ is the rate parameter; thus using the known result of the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) you have

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=n$$

...and similarly for the variance you have that

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=2n$$